# img not stretching to wrappers height and width

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a wavy background on top of my regular background but the image is not stretching all the way out. It has to be position absolute (otherwise it's interfering with my navigation and moves it down by the height of the img). [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/1mjs9kgu/11/).  I already tried `object-fit: fill` which also didn't work. Thanks in advance

My code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
  height: 5000px;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: ;
  opacity: 15%;
}

#navwrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, #0061ff, #60efff);
  background-size: 400% 400%;

  -webkit-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="navwrapper">
       <div id="background"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/RZzwCTQz/Zeichenfla-che-92.png"></div>

</nav>
```

Comment: why don't use css `background` to fill img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying css to #background apply it in #background img thats where you want to change object fit property.

replace this

```
#background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: ;
  opacity: 15%;
}
```

with this

```
#background img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 15%;
}
```

### You can check the output below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
  height: 5000px;
}

#background img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: ;
  opacity: 15%;
}

#navwrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, #0061ff, #60efff);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimationName 10s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 94%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 7%
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="navwrapper">
  <div id="background"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/RZzwCTQz/Zeichenfla-che-92.png"></div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this property

```
#background{
      background:url(...);
      background-position: center !important;
      background-size: cover !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 500px;
      width:100%
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `width` and `height` to `100%` for an image that it should all space of container:

```
#background img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}
```